# How can I search for an old answer of mine when the question is seemingly deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

*"You don't need to know everything. You merely need to know where to look it up."*

Often a time, when trying to remember a specific solution to a problem, I don't remember the solution exactly, but I do remember that I had researched one and made an answer about it at EE.SE. I then usually manage to find the answer containing the details using the `user:me keywords` search term. This is exactly what StackExchange tries to provide: a Q&A repository.

Can it be that if a question has been deleted, I can't find my answers to it? (I know how I can find my own deleted answers.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that normal users can't search deleted questions or their answers (there are rare situations when a question can be deleted even after it has answers, and the answers then get deleted too).

I don't believe the search term you used `user:me keywords` will search your own deleted answers either.

The best I can suggest is to look through your deleted answers. Here is a link which will work for anyone who clicks on it, to see their own deleted answers on the main EE.SE site:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-answers/current

Comment: I know that I need the `deleted:1` term to find answers/questions of mine that are deleted, but didn't consider it relevant for the question.

Comment: @tobalt - Hi, I was getting slightly confused with the question I was trying to answer, as there are multiple variations e.g. wanting to search in *own* deleted answers vs. search in all deleted answers / > 10k user or not / mod or not etc. (lots of different answers). Then you mentioned "can't find" which made me stop thinking about *search* and made me want to tell you about that link to the *list*. || So I'm not sure I've really answered what you wanted. If not, feel free to unaccept my answer and accept Voltage Spike's with that link to the Meta article, as that might be more helpful :)

Comment: The question here was: How can I (>10k rep) find one of my (not deleted) answers if their parent question has been deleted. You answered it by stating that it is generally impossible. So all is fine +1 

Comment: @tobalt - Hi, Thanks for clarifying. In that case, if the parent question was deleted, then any answer on that question also gets deleted. Those deleted answers (due to the parent question being deleted) then behave like any other deleted answers i.e. your (now-deleted) answer will appear in the list of your deleted answers (using the link in my answer) & it *should* be searchable by you using `deleted:1 user:me keywords`. || If you have a specific answer you're trying to find, we can try to figure out what's happening in a short chat (either main chat or a temp chatroom), if you want that.

Comment: Ah so it is possible. Thanks Sam! I have already found it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have over 10k rep you can see deleted answers, otherwise have a mod search it for you.

[How to find my deleted answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105835/how-to-find-my-deleted-answer)